# Using react-native-gesture-handler (RNGH) inside a modal with wix/react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-modal

I'm trying to use RNGH components like `TouchableOpacity` inside a `react-native-modal` combined with `wix/react-native-navigation`. **It doesn't work.** When I tap it, no interaction happened.

Importing `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` seems to be working. The problem is, I want to use `import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-navigation';` because it is more responsive compared to the original.

Could anyone explain why, or a workaround maybe?

Here is my app structure:

```
Wix react-native-navigation
|
|-- gestureHandlerRootHOC( Component (The Screen) )
      |
      |----- <Modal />
      |         |
      |         |------ TouchableOpacity <-- I cannot press this
      |
      |----- TouchableOpacity <-- But I can press this
```

Comment: I just noticed, that this scenario works on Android, but not on iOS

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `react-native`'s `Modal` component creates a native ViewController that's not managed by `react-native-navigation`, thus not wrapped with the `gestureHandlerRootHOC`.

I'd suggest showing a RNN modal via `Navigation.showModal(). That way your modal is also a registered screen wrapped with the` gestureHandlerRootHOC`.

Comment: I'd love to use Navigation.showModal(), especially in Apple devices. Apple is supporting Modal scenario, where Android just show a full-screen page 